# window.beforeunload prompt does not hide the ajax update progress

Tags: jquery, ajax, updatepanel, updateprogress

I used the code capturing the

```
$(window).on('beforeunload unload', function (element) { 
  return 'Are you sure you want to leave?';
});
```

On the same page I have a update panel and a update progress.
If user navigates to other page by clicking on button the prompt message appears and the update progress also kick in.

If the user select no in the alert window and stays on the same page the update progress still stays on in visible state.

Is there any way that I can capture the user's response to the "Changes may not be saved prompt" so based on the result I will hide the update progress image.

```
 <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="ProductSelectorContainerPanel" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                <ContentTemplate>

 <asp:Button runat="server" ID="DoPartialPostBack" OnClick="DoPartialPostBack_Click" Text="Do Postback"/>

   </ContentTemplate>
 </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

.cs Code

> protected void DoPartialPostBack_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
>           {
>               Response.Redirect("page2.aspx");
>           }

Now if you add a debugger the Response redirect gets called in first. Which will call the beforeunload  code for the jquery. and based on the selected result(in my case stay) the update progress will fire as its a postback.

Comment: *"...and the update progress also kick in"* Why? That would seem to be the thing you need to fix, rather than worrying about what answer they give to the prompt.

Answer (score 0):

> ...so based on the result I will hide the update progress image

Just hide it in the `beforeunload` handler. If the user leaves the page, it doesn't matter whether it's hidden; they've left the page. If they don't, you have the result you want.

Comment: The update progress fires after I click  on the yes button for the prompt.So if I cannot hide it as update progress is not yet visible.

Comment: @Anurag.Desai: I suspect if you try it, you'll find it works. Remember that what you see when a stop-the-world modal like that is showing isn't always an up-to-date reflection of the DOM. If that's not it, you'll need to update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-do-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do-tha)).

Answer (score 0):

I changed code for adding a full postback trigger for the button.
So the button does behavior like a normal button and button call is stopped when user selects the no in the alert.